# Form fine in IE not chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have a straightforward **html** form that woks fine in **IE** but none of it works in **chrome**.  If it matters, file extension is "**.shtml**".  Inputs won't work nor selects and submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You may check on your flash settings in chrome.